# MS WordのルビをVBAで削除したい

Tags: vba, ms-word

皆さん、お疲れ様です。

ふりがなを追加するには、このコードを使用しています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602598/how-to-add-phonetic-guides-to-all-the-texts-at-once

VBAでルビを削除するには、どうすればよいでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

ハシ

Answer (score 1):

[`Range.PhoneticGuide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/office/ff840645.aspx) メソッドのTextパラメータに空文字列を指定することで、ルビを削除することができます。対象となる `Range` オブジェクトを得るには、例えば `ActiveDocument.Fields` プロパティなどが使えます。

```
Sub 文章内の全てのルビを削除()
For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
  f.Select
  Selection.Range.PhoneticGuide ""
Next
End Sub
```

なおこのプロパティにはルビ以外のフィールドコードも含まれていますが、それらに対して `PhoneticGuide` メソッドを使うとそのフィールドコードが壊れてしまいます。そのようなケースを避ける必要があれば、`Field.Code.FormattedText` や `Field.Type` などでそれらしいかどうかを判別する必要があります。

参考

- [ルビ削除のマクロの仕様？ - Goo知恵袋](http://otasuke.goo-net.com/qa3338446.html)
- [Word2007(ワード2007)実用編：フィールドコードの使い方](http://www.eurus.dti.ne.jp/~yoneyama/Word2007/word2007-field.html)